# How do I switch between layouts properly?

Tags: java, android

So basically I am creating a very simple app that has only 2 layouts and I want to go from one to another properly. I know from what I have read that if you want to create a new screen/activity on the same project, you first have to create the new layout (which I already did), and I know that now I have to create the activity and do something to the manifesto, but I do not know what that is. I have seem some youtube videos about but I do not know if the fact that if I want my new activity to be the default one changes anything.

As you will be able to see in the attached pictures, "activity_questions" was the first layout that I had back when I created the project. Now I want to create a new screen/layout for the app which is the "noquestions_layout" one. However, I want to make the new layout that I created my main screen/activity for the user, and my "activity_questions" the one that will pop whenever my database feeds some information to the app.

How can I do all this? I know this is one of the things that you only need to learn once...and this might sound very simple, and I apologize if is something newbie. I basically started to learn android studio not too long ago.

You do not need to tell me all the code that I need to put in my app, just some basic examples with guidance... "create Y here, and then put X there"

[image: First layout/activity]

[image: New Wanted layout/activity]

Comment: Please read the "First App" documentation on Android developers site. It covers all the things you just asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Create two Activities, Say, Activity_A and Activity_B.

For the first activity, place this code in the manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity_A">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For the second activity, use this code:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity ">
</activity>
```

Here, the Activity that launches when the app starts is the Activity_A, because of the intent filter in the manifest of the Activity_A:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now, Since you already have your Activities, the layouts ready, where Activity_A is started as soon as the app is started, to launch Activity_B from Activity_A, use this code:

```
Intent intentTour = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
intentTour.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); //This line is optional, better to use it because it won't create multiple instances of the launching Activity.
startActivity(intentTour);
```

Comment: Thank you! now I get why it is happening and how to do it, which is what I wanted in the first place. I appreciate it For your last comment, what would I need to do if I wanted to Activity_B whenever a database sends some information to the app?

Comment: You mean you want to launch Activity_B whenever a database send some information to the app?

Comment: Correct, sorry if my internet is messy. Basically like a google rewards kind of app. -My database will be feeding some questions to the app, and I want Activity_B to launch with that questions whenever the question is received. I have already done the database (MySQL) and an script to get the data out of it (php script)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about the google rewards app but, whenever you receive the data, use the code I mentioned above to launch the desired Activity.

Intent intentTour = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
intentTour.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); //This line is optional, better to use it because it won't create multiple instances of the launching Activity.
startActivity(intentTour);

Answer (score 1):

For new screen layout create a new activity and call that layout file there.

To make any activity as your first activity when app starts, you have to go to manifest and cut paste the intent filter tag to the activity you want to start first

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Suppose you want to make another activity example .SecondActivity as starting activity cut above intent filter tag and paste it there like this

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity ">

        </activity>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer how to go from one Activity to the other.

Comment: he was also confused on what to do with manifest when making a activity starting activity in the app. It was the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new activity in Android Studio, Studio will create the corresponding resource file as well as manifest entry for your activity.

Say for example, you have two activities QuestionsActivity and NoQuestionsActivity. QuestionsActivity will be your default launch activity. To make NoQuestionsActivity your launch actvity. Open the manifest file and under activity tag of NoQuestionsActivity include the intent filter and remove intent filter from

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".QuestionsActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".NoQuestionsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

To switch from one activity to another, say from NoQuestionsActivity to QuestionsActivity use intent the following code-

```
Intent questionsIntent = new Intent(NoQuestionsActivity.this, QuestionsActivity.class);
startActivity(questionsIntent);
```

If you want to pass value to QuestionsActivity pass it as extras in the intnet.

Hope this will help.